# Making a dataframe from a dictionary of pd Series of varying lengths

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dict of series of varying lengths. I want to put them all into one df. I would like to add the index of each series to the index as well.

Example:

```
    dict = {'2021-07-16': pd.Series({125.0:229.78}), 
            '2021-07-23' : pd.Series({170.0 : 184.65, 175.0 : 179.80})}
```

What I want (sorry don't know how tables work):

```
pd = | index |  col1   | col2   |
     | 125.0 | 229.78  | NULL   |
     | 170.0 | NULL    | 184.65 |
     | 175.0 | NULL    | 179.80 |
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
call_series_pd = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in test.items()]))
```

When I do this, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

This would be because some of the series' indices overlap.

Comment: Please post a valid dictionary. We can't copy/paste and test with your `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df = pd.concat(
    [s.to_frame().reset_index() for s in dct.values()],
    axis=1,
)
df.columns = [
    c for i in range(1, len(dct) + 1) for c in (f"col{i}_index", f"col{i}")
]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1_index    col1  col2_index    col2
0       125.0  229.78       170.0  184.65
1       130.0  224.83       175.0  179.80
2       135.0  219.78       180.0  174.78
3       140.0  214.73       185.0  169.68
4       145.0  209.63       190.0  164.78
5       490.0    0.01       445.0    0.01
6       500.0    0.01       450.0    0.02
7       520.0    0.01       455.0    0.01
8       540.0    0.01       460.0    0.01
9       560.0    0.01       465.0    0.01
```

---

EDIT: Another solution:

```py
dct = {
    "2021-07-16": pd.Series({125.0: 229.78}),
    "2021-07-23": pd.Series({170.0: 184.65, 175.0: 179.80}),
}

data = pd.DataFrame(dct.values()).T
data.columns = "col_" + (data.columns + 1).astype(str)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
        col_1   col_2
125.0  229.78     NaN
170.0     NaN  184.65
175.0     NaN  179.80
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I would be able to get them all onto the same index?

Comment: @ChrisB Try `df.melt(["col1", "col2"]).drop("variable", 1).set_index("value").sort_index()`

Comment: hm, error. Random columns are being named '0'. what is c in the second equation above?